# Objective-c: валится приложение при объявлении связи

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Доброго времени суток. Имеется проект на Objective c.
Есть контроллер с элементом tableView и есть класс tableViewCell (в котором есть два лэйбла), из которого я беру ячейку для tableView. И все это отлично работает до тех пор, пока я не объявлю связи для любого лэйбла.
Приложение валится со следующей ошибкой:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key name.'

Связь объявляю через file's owner.

Код объявления связи в хэдере tableViewCell:

```
@interface CafeCell:UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_CafeName;
@end
```

Код построения таблицы:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CafeCell";

        CafeCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil){
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];//падает здесь
        }
        return cell;  
}
```

Comment: скиньте код, так проще будет выловить. есть несколько вещей, которые могут привести к такому результату. Например в IB классу дано неправильное имя, или если вы сделали связь а потом что то переименовали и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Все что вам нужно сделать в классе `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CafeCell";
CafeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.lbl_CafeName.text = @"Your text";
```

И не забудьте зарегистрировать ячейку, если она у вас построена в отдельном Xib:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CafeCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CafeCell"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить этот кусок кода:

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

На:

```
cell = [[CafeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

И теперь вы можете задать нужное вам значение вашему UILabel:

```
cell.lbl_CafeName.text = yourValue;
```